# How to restore pre-update OS from Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, restore

I've never actually restored with Time Machine, not sure how it works.

My machine is messed up since updating to a Yosemite Beta and installing nvidia drivers.

How do I go back a few days?

I ONLY want to restore the system/drivers, NOT my User folder, etc.
Can I just restore `/System`, `/Library`, and `/Applications` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for a certain file or folder, start by connecting the external drive that you use for Time Machine backups or by making sure that you can connect to your Time Capsule. Click the Time Machine item in the menu bar at the top of your screen (it looks like a clock with an arrow running counterclockwise around it), and choose Enter Time Machine. Here, all of your saved backups will appear in chronological order. Use the visual timeline on the right side to scroll through your backups and look for specific items or folders.

Select the file or folder you want, and press the Restore button. The file(s)/folder(s) will automatically be copied to your desktop or to the file’s original folder. This may take some time, depending on the size of the transfer.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. How do I use TM to restore just the system? Do what you say but with the /System folder?

Comment: In the time machine app you can select the folders you want to reinstall. If you want the `/System`, navigate to that folder and press restore.

Comment: And will that revert my system to pre-update? Is that the only folder I need? Any hidden folders /usr, /var or whatever? What about /Library?

Comment: I don't think so. I recommend to do a full restore. Otherwise the results can be unpredictable.

Comment: Full restore meaning reboot into recovery and restore from there? Will that preserve my non-backed up root directories?

Comment: Yes, meant reboot into recovery mode, and No, won't preserve any non backed files. But keep in mind that if you only restore the folders you said in you question, your system will probably be inestable.