# Is it possible to revert to non-beta Yosemite?

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

I signed up for Yosemite betas at https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/ but am having issues.

Is there any way to go back the "standard" version of Yosemite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I re-install Mavericks on rMBP without wiping drive?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168747/how-do-i-re-install-mavericks-on-rmbp-without-wiping-drive)

Comment: duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168748/46541 http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168747/46541

Comment: It's not a duplicate. They are similar questions, but not identical. I'm exploring my options.

Comment: sorry, it looks to me like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

On `System Preferences → App Store` you have an option called `Your computer is set to receive pre-releases Software Update seeds`, use the button `Change` and select `Do Not Show Pre-release Updates`.

Comment: Doesn't that just prevent future updates? I want to "uninstall" the betas, and go back to the "regular" version 10.10.1 or .0

Comment: It's not posible. You have to disable the option I told you and wait until the next release. Otherwise, you will have to reinstall your system.